# Zooming d3js graph corresponding to nodes count

Tags: d3.js, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to display my full tree within fixed height and width.

Since I dont know the exact nodes count , tree nodes went out of focus.

I have tried to adjust the zoom scale (manually) to display within the boundaries.

I just want to adjust the zoom scale automatically depends on the nodes count

Can anyone help me to sortout this issue.

```js
var treeData = {
  "name": "Share point Server 2019",
  "id": "a093F0000078Id5QAE",
  "children": [{
      "name": "is extended by",
      "level": "sub node",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Share point Server 2019",
        "id": "a093F0000078Id5QAE"
      }]
    },
    {
      "name": "manages",
      "level": "sub node",
      "children": [{
          "name": "HPE ProLiant ML350 Tower",
          "id": "a093F0000078IcHQAU"
        },
        {
          "name": "HPE ProLiant ML350 Tower",
          "id": "a093F0000078IcHQAU"
        },
        {
          "name": "HPE ProLiant ML350 Tower",
          "id": "a093F0000078IcHQAU"
        },
        {
          "name": "HPE ProLiant ML350 Tower",
          "id": "a093F0000078IcHQAU"
        },
        {
          "name": "HPE ProLiant ML350 Tower",
          "id": "a093F0000078IcHQAU"
        },
        {
          "name": "HPE ProLiant ML350 Tower",
          "id": "a093F0000078IcHQAU"
        },
        {
          "name": "HPE ProLiant ML350 Tower",
          "id": "a093F0000078IcHQAU"
        },
        {
          "name": "HPE ProLiant ML350 Tower",
          "id": "a093F0000078IcHQAU"
        },
        {
          "name": "HPE ProLiant ML350 Tower",
          "id": "a093F0000078IcHQAU"
        },
        {
          "name": "HPE ProLiant ML350 Tower",
          "id": "a093F0000078IcHQAU"
        },
        {
          "name": "HPE ProLiant ML350 Tower",
          "id": "a093F0000078IcHQAU"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "is operated by",
      "level": "sub node",
      "children": [{
          "name": "Power point SH-20",
          "id": "a093F00000794ZWQAY"
        },
        {
          "name": "Power point SH-20",
          "id": "a093F00000794ZWQAY"
        },
        {
          "name": "Power point SH-20",
          "id": "a093F00000794ZWQAY"
        },
        {
          "name": "Power point SH-20",
          "id": "a093F00000794ZWQAY"
        },
        {
          "name": "Power point SH-20",
          "id": "a093F00000794ZWQAY"
        },
        {
          "name": "Power point SH-20",
          "id": "a093F00000794ZWQAY"
        },
        {
          "name": "Power point SH-20",
          "id": "a093F00000794ZWQAY"
        },
        {
          "name": "Power point SH-20",
          "id": "a093F00000794ZWQAY"
        },
        {
          "name": "Power point SH-20",
          "id": "a093F00000794ZWQAY"
        },
        {
          "name": "Power point SH-20",
          "id": "a093F00000794ZWQAY"
        },
        {
          "name": "Power point SH-20",
          "id": "a093F00000794ZWQAY"
        },
        {
          "name": "Power point SH-20",
          "id": "a093F00000794ZWQAY"
        },
        {
          "name": "Power point SH-20",
          "id": "a093F00000794ZWQAY"
        },
        {
          "name": "Power point SH-20",
          "id": "a093F00000794ZWQAY"
        },
        {
          "name": "Power point SH-20",
          "id": "a093F00000794ZWQAY"
        },
        {
          "name": "Power point SH-20",
          "id": "a093F00000794ZWQAY"
        },
        {
          "name": "Power point SH-20",
          "id": "a093F00000794ZWQAY"
        },
        {
          "name": "Power point SH-20",
          "id": "a093F00000794ZWQAY"
        },
        {
          "name": "Power point SH-20",
          "id": "a093F00000794ZWQAY"
        },
        {
          "name": "Power point SH-20",
          "id": "a093F00000794ZWQAY"
        },
        {
          "name": "Power point SH-20",
          "id": "a093F00000794ZWQAY"
        },
        {
          "name": "Power point SH-20",
          "id": "a093F00000794ZWQAY"
        },
        {
          "name": "Power point SH-20",
          "id": "a093F00000794ZWQAY"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
var nodeCount = 53;
var scale = 1,
  svgHeight = 200,
  nodeCount = 13;;
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 90,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 90
  },
  width = window.outerWidth,
  height = window.outerHeight;
var focused = false;
console.log('scale', scale)
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function() {
    svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
  })).on("dblclick.zoom", null)
  .attr("width", "1000")
  .attr("height", 800)
  .append("g")
svg.attr("transform", function(d) {

  return "translate(" +
    (450) + "," + (svgHeight) + ")scale(" + scale + ")";
});


var nodeCount = 15;
var i = 0,
  duration = 750,
  root;
// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) {
  return d.children;
});
root.x0 = height;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
if (typeof collapse === 'undefined')
  root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}

function update(source) {

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
    links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);
  let left = root;
  let right = root;
  var dx = ((nodeCount * 18) / 1000);
  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d, index) {
    d.y = d.depth * 180;
    d.x = d.x * ((nodeCount * 18) / 1000);

  });
  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + (source.y0) + "," + (source.x0) + ")";
    })
    .on('click', d => {
      // d3.event.preventDefault();

      component.set("v.nodeName", d.data.name);
    })
    .on("dblclick", click);


  // Add Circle for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr('r', 1e-6)
    .style('stroke', 'steelblue')
    .style('stroke-width', '3px');

  // Add labels for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('text')
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.name;
    });

  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + (d.y) + "," + (d.x) + ")";
    });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
    .attr('r', 3)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    })
    .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + (source.y) + "," + source.x + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle')
    .attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text')
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style('fill', "none")
    .style('stroke', "#ccc")
    .style('stroke-width', "2px")
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      }
      return diagonal(o, o)
    });

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      return diagonal(d, d.parent)
    });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      }
      return diagonal(o, o)
    })
    .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  function diagonal(s, d) {
    var path = "M" + d.y + "," + d.x +
      "C" + (d.y + s.y) / 2 + "," + d.x +
      " " + (d.y + s.y) / 2 + "," + s.x +
      " " + s.y + "," + s.x;

    return path;
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {

  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  margin: 50px;
}

.grid .tick {
  stroke: lightgrey;
  opacity: 0.7;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid path {
  stroke-width: 0;
}

.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #bbb;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis text {
  fill: #555;
}

.axis line {
  stroke: #e7e7e7;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis .axis-label {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.dot {
  /* consider the stroke-with the mouse detect radius? */
  stroke: transparent;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dot:hover {
  stroke: rgba(68, 127, 255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<div style="background:white" id="body"></div>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm too late, but I had a similar issue and what I did was to use getBounds() method on the map object, which returns an object like {x, y, width, height}, that you can later use to calculate the zoom factor and positioning, since you can easily find out container's size.

Comment: thanks for your response @Carles. Can you please share your code or do a snippet.Thanks

Comment: Well, this deppends on your implementation, just take the DOM object belonging to your graph and get the bounds using the function. I normally work in SVG pictures, but instead of using the svg object, I normally have a main layer/group that contains all the drawing, then I reference that object: var g = document.getElementById('mysvg').getElementById("myg"); After this I simply use g.getBounds(); If you would use getBounds on your main SVG object, depending on your code you could get the size of the view, not the actual size of the drawing.

Comment: Another very important thing: in order to get the real dimensions, you need to, multiply the numbers with the current Scale factor, that can be taken from the current zoom object or transform, being "k" the parameter of your interest: transform.k